# Passing useState to other pages

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have setup a react native application and am looking for help in how I would pass some useState values down to my other pages?

My App.js export looks like this.

```
export default function App() {
  const AppState = {
    firstName: "Jim",
    lastName: "Smith"
  }
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState);

  return (
       <NavigationContainer>
          <Navigator />
          <NavBar />
       </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

The `< Navigator />` is where I've setup the Stack Navigator, and it looks like this.

```
export default function AppNavigator() {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

When the app loads, the initial route points it to Home.js. How would I then get the appState configured from App.js, to be available in Home.js?

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
    <Text>My name is: {firstName] {lastName]</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have tried passing the appState like this `< Navigator ref={appState} />` but this didn't work.

I have also tried exporting the `App()` with like this `App{appState}` and like this `App{{appState}}` but neither of these worked.

Help! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is just to pass props down to child components.

```
function Page(props) {
  const user = props.user;
  return <Avatar user={user} />;
}

<Page user={user} />
```

[Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.